# SVG element from an array

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I am trying to load images into a svg canvas from an array and I am not able to make this code work.

I am trying to debug it with Chrome and I am not able to. The image is blank and I don't know how to proceed.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
                background-image:url('BG.png')
     }
</style>
<title>Drag And Drop</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function(){
    var NumImages = [
                { 'x' :200, 'y':90, 'width': 450, 'height':200, 'href' : 'numbers.jpeg'  },
];
var circleData = [
   { "cx": 20, "cy": 20, "radius": 20, "color" : "green" },
   { "cx": 70, "cy": 70, "radius": 20, "color" : "purple" }];


 var rectangleData = [
   { "rx": 110, "ry": 110, "height": 30, "width": 30, "color" : "blue" },
   { "rx": 160, "ry": 160, "height": 30, "width": 30, "color" : "red" }];

    var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                                .attr("width",700)
                                                .attr("height",700)
                                                .attr("margin-top", 100);


    var images = svgContainer.selectAll("image")
        .data(NumImages)
        .enter()
        .append("image");

    svgContainer.append("image")
        .attr('x',200)
        .attr('y',90)
        .attr('width', 50)
        .attr('height', 200)    
        .attr("xlink:href", "2-image.jpg");
    };

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done all the hard work, you just need to adjust the last couple of lines.  You need to use the data that you've bound to the images variable so try this;

```
images
    .attr('x', function (d,i) { return d.x; })
    .attr('y', function (d,i) { return d.y; })
    .attr('width', function (d,i) { return d.width; })
    .attr('height', function (d,i) { return d.height; })    
    .attr("xlink:href", function (d,i) { return d.href; });
```

Comment: There a quite a few online there's the intro on the [D3](http://d3js.org/) page and there's a link to more tutorials on the left hand side of the page.  Obviously the tutorials by Mike Bostock are worth looking and Scott Murray's tutorials always tutorials always get a good review.  There's also a discussion on google groups that worth looking at [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/nyK7kuP14PY/uoGg1kq_Qw4J)